# Using nn.Linear() and nn.BatchNorm1d() together

Tags: pytorch

I don't understand how BatchNorm1d works when the data is 3D, (batch size, H, W).

**Example**

- Input size: (2,50,70)
- Layer: nn.Linear(70,20)
- Output size: (2,50,20)

If I then include a batch normalisation layer it requires num_features=50:

- BN    : nn.BatchNorm1d(50)

and I don't understand why it isn't 20:

- BN    : nn.BatchNorm1d(20)

Example 1)

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.bn11 = nn.BatchNorm1d(50)
        self.fc11 = nn.Linear(70,20)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        out = self.fc11(inputs)
        out = torch.relu(self.bn11(out))
        return out

model = Net()
inputs = torch.Tensor(2,50,70)
outputs = model(inputs)
```

Example 2)

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.bn11 = nn.BatchNorm1d(20)
        self.fc11 = nn.Linear(70,20)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        out = self.fc11(inputs)
        out = torch.relu(self.bn11(out))
        return out

model = Net()
inputs = torch.Tensor(2,50,70)
outputs = model(inputs)
```

- Example 1 works.
- Example 2 throws the error:

  - RuntimeError: running_mean should contain 50 elements not 20

**2D example:**

- Input size: (2,70)
- Layer: nn.Linear(70,20)
- BN: nn.BatchNorm1d(20)

I thought the 20 in the BN layer was due to there being 20 nodes output by the linear layer and each one requires a running means/std for the incoming values.

Why in the 3D case, if the linear layer has 20 output nodes, the BN layer doesn't have 20 features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can find the answer inside [`torch.nn.Linear` documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Linear).

It takes `input` of shape `(N, *, I)` and returns `(N, *, O)`, where `I` stands for input dimension and `O` for output dim and `*` are any dimensions between.

If you pass `torch.Tensor(2,50,70)` into `nn.Linear(70,20)`, you get output of shape `(2, 50, 20)` and when you use `BatchNorm1d` it calculates running mean for first non-batch dimension, so it would be 50. That's the reason behind your error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe my question isn't clear or this isn't the place to ask it. But in the 2D case, you have the same number of running means as there are output nodes, and I thought this normalises the output coming out of each node. So I can't wrap my head around why in the 3D case there are 50 running means, there are more running means then there are output nodes, so I don't understand what is being normalised. Hopefully that explains my question better.

Comment: You have the same number of running means as output nodes, but `BatchNorm1d` normalizes to zero mean and one standard deviation only the first dimension. `nn.Linear` for `3D` case outputs tensor `(2, 50, 20)`, statistics are calculated for the first dimension hence you get `50` (first dimension) as the input to be normalized. So `50` running means are needed to fit output from `Linear` so it can be normalized properly. Though it almost never used in `3D` case, at least I'm not aware of the use case. It it clearer what's being normalized now?